# SQL SELECT with GROUP BY, referring back to the group

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I'm a relative SQL beginner, and I'm not entirely sure how to ask what I'm asking (so I'm also not entirely sure how to search for help on it).

I want to use a `SELECT` statement that uses a `GROUP BY` clause to group by a certain attribute, and at the same time refer back to the rows selected by that group. Is there any way to do this? (I'm using, FWIW, SQLite3, but I reckon this is more a question of universal SQL syntax.)

I have a table `population` in which I have data about people and households. Each row is a person, and the people are each grouped into households of anywhere from one to a dozen.

One person in each household (generally the first person, by `uid`) is the head of the household, and has the `head` column set. I want to `GROUP BY` the column `household_id`, and also select the `uid` of each member of the group who is the "head". Is there any way to do that all with one statement?

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT household_id,
    COUNT(uid) AS members   /* The number of members in each household; it works */,
    (SELECT uid FROM "group" WHERE head == 1) /* Only I don't know how to do this */
    FROM population GROUP BY household_id;
```

I tried something like this, and it didn't give me what I want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT household_id,
    COUNT(uid) AS members,
    (SELECT uid FROM population WHERE household_id == household_id AND head == 1) /* <-- here */
    FROM population GROUP BY household_id;
```

But that of course picks the first row in which `household_id` is `household_id`; i.e. the very first row in the table. How do I refer to only the `household_id` that is `DISTINCT` in this particular group?

Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  household_id,
        COUNT(uid) AS members, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN head = 1 THEN uid ELSE NULL END) headID
FROM    population 
GROUP   BY household_id;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6d7ef/2)

Comment: Thanks! That works, but I'm still scratching my head a little as to why. Let me get this straight: for each member of the group, your clause sets "head_id" to either 1 (if "head" == 1) or NULL. And then it finds the MAX of that group, and since everybody in the group is NULL except for the head, it only selects the one who is 1 (the NULLs sink to the bottom).

Comment: you're right. I don't have to explain abount `COUNT()` because I know you already knew it. You are puzzled on this line: `MAX(CASE WHEN head = 1 THEN uid ELSE NULL END)` right? Remember that you are aggregating the records by `household_id`, so it runs on all records searching for the `head = 1`. If it is found, then values of that certain column is the `uid` and otherwise `null`. To fully understand, execute this query, `SELECT  household_id, CASE WHEN head = 1 THEN uid ELSE NULL END AS HeadID FROM population`.

Comment: Thanks; yes, that's the line I wasn't sure about. I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

You could have been on the right track with

```
SELECT DISTINCT household_id,
COUNT(uid) AS members,
(SELECT uid FROM population WHERE household_id == household_id AND head == 1) /* <-- here */
FROM population GROUP BY household_id;
```

but you need to alias the population table since it is used twice in the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT household_id,
COUNT(uid) AS members,
(SELECT uid FROM population gr_head WHERE pop.household_id = gr_head.household_id AND head == 1) /* <-- here */
FROM population pop GROUP BY household_id;
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, too, and says exactly what I was trying to say. I am still figuring out aliasing; this helps a lot.